# Getting section index from UICollectionView (or the other direction)

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Given a section index, how can I get the `UICollectionReusableView` for the section header?

Or how can I get the section index from the `UICollectionReusableView` object.

I read this: [How to get the index path of a UICollectionView header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104862/how-to-get-the-index-path-of-a-uicollectionview-header), and similar posts but it doesn't work for me.

My sections are dynamic controlled by a `NSFetchedResultsController` and there are multiple inserts, deletion and re-inserts. I suspect that the indices I store in `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath` and `collectionView:didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:forElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` are invalidated at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution. Ugly but it seems to work:

```
- (SUGalleryHeaderView *)headerForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
    NSString *kind = UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader;
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = 
        [self.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (SUGalleryHeaderView *header in headersActive) {
        if (CGRectEqualToRect(header.frame, attr.frame)) {
            return header;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Originally posted here: [Getting supplementary view at specified index in UICollectionView](https://fogofcode.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/getting-supplementary-view-at-specified-index-in-uicollectionview/)